# camel sql-stored component. How to pass INOUT oracle parameter?

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

I am using camel 2.18 camel-sql component for calling stored procedures. Is it possible to call oracle stored procedure which has an INOUT parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INOUT is not supported, only IN or OUT, where IN is the default.